# Added comma separated on the foreach Velocity loop

Tags: velocity

What should I added to the following foreach loop (Velocity codes) to get the final result like appNames=A,B,C

```
   #if($approval.has()) 
   #foreach($item in $approval.rejected)
   #set($appNames =$item.appName)
   #end
   #end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply do add separator to it in the loop and String concatenation

```
#if($approval.has()) 
#set($appNames ="")
#set($separator="")
#foreach($item in $approval.rejected)
#set($appNames  =$appNames  +$separator +$item.appName)
#set($separator = ",")
#end
#end
```

appNames= $appNames

**output**

```
appNames= A,B,C
```

Answer (score 15):

I'd suggest using $foreach.hasNext for a cleaner code:

```
#if($approval.has()) 
  #foreach($item in $approval.rejected)
    #set($appNames =$item.appName)
    #if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
  #end
#end
```